# Excel formula not working - returning unique values horizontally

Tags: excel, excel-formula, row, unique

Is there a way to display unique values from my dataset horizontally WITHOUT using the transpose function:

I have a table like this from G6-G15:

```
**Colour**
Red
Red
Blue
Green
Green
Green
Yellow
Yellow
Yellow
```

My required output is this

```
Blue Green Red Yellow
```

I have tried using this formula to return the unique values horizontally however, it doesn't seem to work
=INDEX(SORT(UNIQUE($G$7:$G$15)),COLUMN(G6))

Comment: I think this is an X-Y problem and you need to debug why `TRANSPOSE` doesn't work for your end users (as per previous comments).

Comment: `=INDEX(SORT(UNIQUE($G$7:$G$15)),COLUMN(A1))` put that in the first cell and copy over.

Comment: @ScottCraner  hi Scott how can I ignore blanks using this formula? I have some missing data within my range

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use SEQUENCE to SPILL right:

```
=INDEX(SORT(UNIQUE($G$7:$G$15)),SEQUENCE(,COUNTA(UNIQUE($G$7:$G$15))))
```

[image]

---

Or we can do the old fashioned drag with:

```
=INDEX(SORT(UNIQUE($G$7:$G$15)),COLUMN(A1))
```

[image]

Comment: Upvoted... but I'm waiting for the... "Oh, this doesn't work for the end user either" comment :-)